# Weird texture scrolling while making shape keys

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, edit-mode, shape-keys

I was in the middle of making shape keys for this model when I noticed that if I had the "Basis" selected and moved some faces the textures wouldn't move, they would stay in place, as you can see with the eyebrow here.

[image: 1]

But If have any shape key selected and move the same faces, the texture comes along as you would expect.

[image: 2]

Is this normal? This is my first time making shape keys so maybe I'm just missing something. It isn't bothering me right now but it might later, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: check the Options panel on the top right ofthe 3D view, see if the Transform Correct Face Attributes is enable, and disable it if it's the case, you'll be able to edit the mesh with the texture following